# Display user data on UITableView obtained from a column typed array of PFUser on Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I created UITableView inside UIView (**UserListVC**) to display user data stored in a column typed array on Parse.com. The column called "**followers**" contains the array of **PFUser objectId** who did like the user in a row (in this case is current user).

In userListVC.m:

```
@implementation UserListViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}    

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

/*
tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"user1", @"user2", nil];
NSLog(@"tableData --> %@", tableData);
*/
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

PFQuery *userQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kPAWParseUserClassKey];
[userQuery whereKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
userQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
[userQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *users, NSError *error)
 {
     if( !error )
     {
         NSArray *array = [users valueForKey:@"followings"];
         for (int i = 0; i <= array.count; i++)

             PFQuery *followingsQuery = [PFUser query];
             [followingsQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[[[users valueForKey:@"followings"] objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:i]];
             followingsQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;

             [followingsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *followings, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     NSLog(@"following names --> %@", [followings valueForKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey]);

                     [tableData addObject:[followings valueForKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey]]; //??
                     [self.tableView reloadData];
                     NSLog(@"table data --> %@", tableData);
                 }
             }];
     }
 }];
}
```

I am now able to extract usernames from the user class by using data array that I get from "**followers**" column and I also have **[self.tableView reloadData];** in async query block but **there is still a problem with tableview not showing usernames obtained from tableData**. If I use sample data ("user1","user2") just for testing, there is no problem.

Here below I show my log from the code:

```
2014-12-31 11:05:00.626 Test[12354:60b] following names --> (
user1name
)
2014-12-31 11:05:00.628 Test[12354:60b] table data --> (
    (
    user1name
    )
)
2014-12-31 11:05:00.631 Test[12354:60b] following names --> (
user2name
)
2014-12-31 11:05:00.633 Test[12354:60b] table data --> (
    (
    user1name
    ),
    (
    user2name
    )
)
```

I think it is better to also provide code for the method **(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** and here it is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"TableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier];
}
NSLog(@"table data xxxxx --> %@", tableData);
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

The above method **NEVER** runs but if I test with my sample data, it does run. To be more specific, my questions would be:

- This is UIView with UITableView inside it. I am not sure how to do **[self.tableView reloadData];** properly. I mean how to declare tableView. In this case I do this:

  ```
  @interface UserListViewController ()
  @property (weak, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;//????
  @end
  ```
- Why the method **(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** never get run?

Comment: What code are you using to "obtain the username from the user class by using data array that I get from "followers" column"?

Comment: I don't know how to do that yet. I have been through a lot of searches but yet to find one.

Comment: If you're receiving object IDs from your initial query, you have yo perform a query using those PFObject IDs to get those user's data.

Comment: I've been thinking how to put this in code. Somehow my brain doesn't work well dealing with array stuff.

Comment: Did you create a Pointer or a Relation in Parse with User?

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman yes that part is ready.

Comment: @LyndseyScott could you please share that piece of code to do what you suggested? I just cannot get my head around this especially as PFObject IDs are in array form.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I am finally able to get usernames but still fail to put those into tableData. Do you know why? Please help.

Comment: @SanitLee Could you put an update under your question to show your current code?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I just realised that I have to initialise tableData first, so I added **tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];** in the code. However this is not yet solution because if I log outside query block tableData will show nothing. That means tableData is never ready. Perhaps I should know how to check if block operation is complete before calling the method **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** in order to show what contained in tableData to tableview.

Comment: @SanitLee Yep, you're 100% right! You can update your tableView inside your async block using `[self.tableView reloadData];` after your `[tableData addObject:[followings valueForKey:kPAWParseUsernameKey]]; //??` line. Great job figuring mostly everything out on your own!

Comment: @LyndseyScott **[self.tableView reloadData]** doesn't help in this case. tableData observed from log outside async query block is still empty. Thank you for jumping in.

Comment: @SanitLee Yeah, that tableData log will still be empty because the tableData isn't ready by the time that line's called since the tableData's being populated in the background during an async block. But if you just need to reload the tableview, do so within the async block. If you want to print out the table data, you'll also have to do so after the line I mentioned in the async block.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I see what you mean but the method  **- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** will need **tableData** to display it on tableview so that is why I have to check tableData outside async block.

Comment: @SanitLee No, you can just reload the table *inside* the async block like I said.

Comment: @LyndseyScott OK well I may have missed something. I'll try to dive into it more. Thanks!

Comment: @LyndseyScott hope you kind enough to see my updated question and let me know if any advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer these 2 specific questions:

- Connect tableView to IBOutlet in .h file and synthesise it in .m file, then:

  ```
  [self.tableView reloadData];
  ```

do the above inside async block.

- The method **(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath** will get run if do as the above suggests.

However there remains other issues but they are out of the scope of this question I believe.